# PLS-00103 Encountered the symbol "END"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm running into the issue PL-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" on the second to last line of the following procedure. The purpose of the procedure is to see if a previous version of an email exists when a new one is sent... and expire the old email. (emails are by default set to a far away expiration date when created so I check to see if the expiration date is further than the current date).

```
PROCEDURE EXPIRE_STUFF_PRC
(
    PI_EMAIL_NBR_STR                 IN  VARCHAR2,
    PO_SUCCESS_FLG                  OUT VARCHAR2, 
    PO_OUT_MSG                      OUT VARCHAR2
) AS 
L_SUCCESS                   VARCHAR2(1) := 'N';
L_EMAIL_ID              NUMBER;
L_PREV_EMAIL_VER_ID     NUMBER := 0;
L_PREV_EMAIL_EXP_DT      DATE;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
    SELECT
        ITEM.EMAIL_ID
        INTO L_EMAIL_ID
    FROM HR_EMAIL        ITEM
    WHERE ITEM.EMAIL_NBR_STR = PI_EMAIL_NBR_STR;
END;

BEGIN
    SELECT
        VER_ID.EMAIL_VER_ID
        INTO L_PREV_EMAIL_VER_ID        
    FROM (
        SELECT
            EMAIL_VER_ID
            FROM HR_EMAIL_VER
            WHERE EMAIL_ID = L_EMAIL_ID
            ORDER BY EMAIL_VER_ID DESC
    ) VER_ID
    WHERE ROWNUM = 2; 
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
        THEN PO_SUCCESS_FLG := 'Y'; 
        PO_OUT_MSG := 'LESS THAN 2 VERSIONS'; 
    END;
END;
BEGIN
    IF (L_PREV_EMAIL_VER_ID > 0) THEN 
        SELECT
            VER.EXP_DT
            INTO L_PREV_EMAIL_EXP_DT
        FROM HR_EMAIL_VER            VER
        WHERE VER.EMAIL_VER_ID = L_PREV_EMAIL_VER_ID;
        IF (L_PREV_EMAIL_EXP_DT > SYSDATE) THEN
            UPDATE HR_EMAIL_VER
            SET EXP_DT = SYSDATE
            WHERE EMAIL_VER_ID = L_PREV_EMAIL_VER_ID;
        END IF;

        PO_SUCCESS_FLG := 'Y';
        PO_OUT_MSG := 'SUCCESS';

    END IF;          
END;
END;
END EXPIRE_STUFF_PRC;
```

I've tried to move around ENDs and BEGINs to no avail...

I've changed the name of stuff due to NDA so if there is any confusion I'll be happy to clarify as I might have missed something.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Indent your code so that nested blocks are indented further than their containing parent blocks. If you've got multiple nested blocks and you can't see at a glance at which level of the code they belong to then you are going to spend extra time debugging issues like this. Take the time to format you code nicely ... it may seem like it is going to take a lot of time but it will actually save you a lot of time and effort in the long run as you will have less to debug.

Comment: @MT0 I had it nicely spaced out in VS Code/Sql Developer but I always seem to have trouble when trying to paste it into stack overflow. do you have any suggestions for how to copy it over?

Comment: Just copy/paste and put  `\`\`\`sql` (3 backticks then the name of the language you're using, or omit the language if you're just pasting data) on the line before it and `\`\`\`` (3 backticks) on the line after it to format it as code. Using that you should not need to change anything in the copy/pasted code. You can also put 4 space characters at the start of every line .... but if you've got a lot of code then it can be a chore to do that so its often easier just to use the backticks.

Comment: @MT0 awesome, just tested it out and it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used unnecessary `BEGIN/END` in your code. There could be a necessity if you want to handle `exceptions` in a particular section. The best way to format and check for syntax is to use a nice code editor.

I have removed all the unwanted BEGIN/END and this should compile fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE expire_stuff_prc (
    pi_email_nbr_str  IN   VARCHAR2,
    po_success_flg    OUT  VARCHAR2,
    po_out_msg        OUT  VARCHAR2
) AS

    l_success            VARCHAR2(1) := 'N';
    l_email_id           NUMBER;
    l_prev_email_ver_id  NUMBER := 0;
    l_prev_email_exp_dt  DATE;
BEGIN

    SELECT
        item.email_id
    INTO l_email_id
    FROM
        hr_email item
    WHERE
        item.email_nbr_str = pi_email_nbr_str;

    BEGIN
        SELECT
            ver_id.email_ver_id
        INTO l_prev_email_ver_id
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    email_ver_id
                FROM
                    hr_email_ver
                WHERE
                    email_id = l_email_id
                ORDER BY
                    email_ver_id DESC
            ) ver_id
        WHERE
            ROWNUM = 2;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
            po_success_flg := 'Y';
            po_out_msg := 'LESS THAN 2 VERSIONS';
    END;

    IF ( l_prev_email_ver_id > 0 ) THEN
        SELECT
            ver.exp_dt
        INTO l_prev_email_exp_dt
        FROM
            hr_email_ver ver
        WHERE
            ver.email_ver_id = l_prev_email_ver_id;

        IF ( l_prev_email_exp_dt > sysdate ) THEN
            UPDATE hr_email_ver
            SET
                exp_dt = sysdate
            WHERE
                email_ver_id = l_prev_email_ver_id;

        END IF;

        po_success_flg := 'Y';
        po_out_msg := 'SUCCESS';
    END IF;

END expire_stuff_prc;
/
```

Comment: What if the first select statement returns no_Data_found/too_many_rows SELECT
        item.email_id INTO l_email_id FROM hr_email item? The caller wouldn't have any clue in this context.

Comment: The code will raise the error, and to handle it OP needs to have a proper exception. I would let OP decide on that, I would certainly not add a bug to his code and post here. Will stick to the scope of the question and that's compilation issue.

Comment: this one worked for me. my proc is being called from another proc which creates the new item and passes it. if no_data_found occurs, it's someone else's fault :) lol

Answer (score 1):

Ideal way to write a stored procedure is to handle all exception for each of the block/statement. You have one additional END that has to be removed, additionally i have added messages to be returned when first and last block goes into any exception.
Block is in sense logically grouped DML operation, it can be just a single select or group of DML operation.Decision to be taken based on the business logic.

```
PROCEDURE EXPIRE_STUFF_PRC
(
    PI_EMAIL_NBR_STR                 IN  VARCHAR2,
    PO_SUCCESS_FLG                  OUT VARCHAR2, 
    PO_OUT_MSG                      OUT VARCHAR2
) AS 
L_SUCCESS                   VARCHAR2(1) := 'N';
L_EMAIL_ID              NUMBER;
L_PREV_EMAIL_VER_ID     NUMBER := 0;
L_PREV_EMAIL_EXP_DT      DATE;

BEGIN
    BEGIN
    SELECT
        ITEM.EMAIL_ID
        INTO L_EMAIL_ID
    FROM HR_EMAIL        ITEM
    WHERE ITEM.EMAIL_NBR_STR = PI_EMAIL_NBR_STR;

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    PO_SUCCESS_FLG := 'Y'; 
    PO_OUT_MSG := 'COULD NOT FETCH EMAIL_ID'; 
   END;

BEGIN
    SELECT
        VER_ID.EMAIL_VER_ID
        INTO L_PREV_EMAIL_VER_ID        
    FROM (
        SELECT
            EMAIL_VER_ID
            FROM HR_EMAIL_VER
            WHERE EMAIL_ID = L_EMAIL_ID
            ORDER BY EMAIL_VER_ID DESC
    ) VER_ID
    WHERE ROWNUM = 2; 
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
        THEN PO_SUCCESS_FLG := 'Y'; 
        PO_OUT_MSG := 'LESS THAN 2 VERSIONS'; 
    END;

BEGIN
    IF (L_PREV_EMAIL_VER_ID > 0) THEN 
        SELECT
            VER.EXP_DT
            INTO L_PREV_EMAIL_EXP_DT
        FROM HR_EMAIL_VER            VER
        WHERE VER.EMAIL_VER_ID = L_PREV_EMAIL_VER_ID;
        IF (L_PREV_EMAIL_EXP_DT > SYSDATE) THEN
            UPDATE HR_EMAIL_VER
            SET EXP_DT = SYSDATE
            WHERE EMAIL_VER_ID = L_PREV_EMAIL_VER_ID;
        END IF;

        PO_SUCCESS_FLG := 'Y';
        PO_OUT_MSG := 'SUCCESS';

    END IF;    
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        PO_SUCCESS_FLG := 'Y';
        PO_OUT_MSG := 'UNABLE TO UPDATE HR_EMAIL_VER';   
END;
END EXPIRE_STUFF_PRC;
```

Comment: `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS` is almost always a **bug**.  You are just dumping all exceptions into one place and hide it. See [**WHEN OTHERS - A Bug**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/)

Comment: Your blog is referring to EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL , that i agree is a bug, but not when you have handle it appropriately. In this scenario it returns an error back to the caller.OP can modify appropriately.You are comparing APPLEs and BANANA's.

Comment: I don't see how without `RAISE` how it would **return** the error? This is not error handling, and should be avoided. Either handle the error, or leave it. The `THEN NULL` is just an example, the bug is `WHEN OTHERS` without a `RAISE`.

Comment: I don't know the Use case to handle the exception, its upto OP to decide how to handle it. PO_OUT_MSG returns a message and that way caller know an error has been encountered.

Comment: It's alright, I ain't nit picking here. I was just helping you as many developers make this mistake. I have explained you and also provided you a good read. If you don't agree, it's up to you. But you cannot disagree with Tom https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/pokemon-and-when-others.html Stay safe !!!